# Divide PHP errors and Application Errors

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I'm working on an Application and a question occurred. I was thinking of letting PHP errors a side (they would be log in the database or in a file) and manage other errors (such as "Your username is not valid" or "Your typed the wrong password" or "The image could not be loaded") with the so famous try-catch method. Is it good to completely manage this kind of errors only with try-catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of exceptions is it's behavior of "petite mort", a local `die()` inside `try{}` block, preventing further code from execution.

While it's quite handy in handling application errors, it become not so good when dealing with validating user input. If a user made 3 mistakes filling a form, it would be merciful to show them all at once, not one after another.

You rather need POST/Redirect/GET pattern to handle user errors:

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think: It is not, because this are not errors, or exception, but simply invalid input. They are also quite common and in this context not an exception in the meaning of the word.

On the other hand, because every exception breaks the current execution, it may lead to unexpected behaviour, when some code is not executed, just because someone entered an unknown username or something. In case of errors, or exceptions, you usually want to stop the execution, because you assume that the execution is not (reasonable) possible (until you catch the exception and go on).

Comment: Catching an exception will not break the execution. I tried to catch and exception and after that echo 'Something' and the string is shown.

Comment: I mean, at least the code beetween `throw` and the matching `catch` is skipped. Of course, if there is no code, nothing is skipped ;) But if you always catch exceptions right after they are thrown, why do you throw them at all? And depending on how/where you react on exceptions, the paths an application can take can get very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For enduser errors you should introduce a separate application level handling system.

Exceptions are useful for handling error conditions (errors that arise on production), while custom E_USER_ errors are the best fit for signaling data/debug/security issues (anything that should be handled at development stage).

Comment: Are there any tutorial on how to better manage enduser errors?

Comment: @Charlie: I'm not aware of any. And there is certainly no standardized/best practice way to do it. Every application seems to require a custom mechanism. (Most frameworks provide some limited method to handle form validation at least.)

Comment: @Charlie just validate user data in order and collect errors into array. Then finally check if this array is empty and then branch your code to save data or show the form back along with found errors

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom Log class I wrote, and set it up as the default error handler and exception handler, as well as providing "debug", "info", "warning", "success" and "deprecated" methods for manually logging (and optionally displaying) messages.

The bonus is, it shows a dump of the variables in the current scope when an actual error occurs, rather than just telling you where it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Errors and exceptions are a technical matter while validation it's business mater.
IFs handle Business, TRY/CATCH handles technical stuff they do not mix and you should not mix them. There are times when you must use an if which throws an exception (PHP stuff) but that is the necessity at framework/architecture level for example

```
if(database_error_handle_raises_error()) {
     throw new MyDatabaseException(driver_raised_error);
}
```

this way you can better control the errors. But the rule stays:
Try/Catch/Throw = technical
If/Else Switch =  business