# Adding validation into PDO

Tags: php, forms, pdo

Got this working how I want, but what updates can i do to it to make it better?

code: ----------------------------------------

```
  $odb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db371885849', $user, $pass);
  $odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];

                        $q = "INSERT INTO jobform(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email);";
                        $query = $odb->prepare($q);
                        $results = $query->execute(array(
                        ":firstname" => $firstname,
                        ":lastname" => $lastname,
                        ":email" => $email
                ));
                }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++Updated Working ++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
 $odb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db371885849', $user, $pass);
  $odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
 if (!empty($firstname))
{

                        $q = "INSERT INTO jobform(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email);";
                        $query = $odb->prepare($q);
                        $results = $query->execute(array(
                        ":firstname" => $firstname,
                        ":lastname" => $lastname,
                        ":email" => $email
                ));
                } else {
            echo "not today";
        }
                }
```

Comment: Try using `empty(trim($_POST...`

Comment: Why do you think it's ever related to PDO?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152223/divide-php-errors-and-application-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];

                    $q = "INSERT INTO jobform(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email);";
                    $query = $odb->prepare($q);
                    $results = $query->execute(array(
                    ":firstname" => $firstname,
                    ":lastname" => $lastname,
                    ":email" => $email
            ));
        }else echo 'make an error';
```

Comment: why -1? explain yourself

Comment: I was about to ask the same question o_O
+1 from me.

Comment: The `firstname` word occurred 7 times in this little snippet, if I am not mistaken. Don't you find it's a little bit too much?

Comment: Ok so in this your checking to see if the feilds are empty before moving on, what would be a better way to cut down the amount of times firstname is used?

Comment: Is this a problem? You can call the var also $pig but i don't see the problem

Comment: Surley with coding practise's the repeation of a varible isn't a great way to do things? I don't have a particular problem, just trying to teach myself the correct way to do things as I go along is all. Thanks for the information though, I'll try it right now!

Comment: I don't see problems in possible repeated names, however in the execute you could pass directly the POST vars, but i don't know if you want add some others controls

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need no validation at all.
So, how I'd did it, based on the code from the tag wiki

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $allowed = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO jobform SET ".pdoSet($fields,$values);
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute($values);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
```

However, if you want to *validate* user input, you'd meed more complex code:

```
<?  
$allowed = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['firstname']) $err[] = "Firstname is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['lastname'])  $err[] = "Lastname is required";  
  if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) {
     $err[] = "Wrong email format";
  }

  if (!$err) {  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO jobform SET ".pdoSet($fields,$values);
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute($values);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
    foreach ($allowed as => $val) {
      $form[$val] = '';
    }
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, pdoSet is new to me, Il see if I can develop this into my script, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

PDO is used to communicate with the database, not to validate values (apart from quoting them for safe inserts). You will have to perform validation before you get to launching your SQL queries with PDO:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (
        // your empty() checks
    ) {
        // your query
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so this code should be set up before the query connection, set up with validation for the varibles?

Comment: You can connect earlier, connection isn't a problem. What I want to say is that you should validate your fields manually and once you're absolutely sure they all validate, you can move on to launching an `INSERT` query. To make things easier, you could also consider using some PHP framework, or at least the validator component thereof. Zend Framework has a decent and rather complete set of validators which you can use standalone.